# What will happen if there is something else also with petrol in car

Tags: engine, fuel-system, car

Today someone broke my car fuel outer case and taken out fuel.
I came home by driving but then i have now one doubt in my mind.

What if he put something else in tank like `water, sand,` etc in there.

Although i didn't find any traces of those near fuel tank but not sure.

So i want to know what will happen if something is there and when i will notice something

Comment: What type of vehicle did this happen on? There are ways to check by removing the fuel pump in some cars, and others not. More information about what kind of car you drive will give us a chance to give you a coherent answer.

Comment: @Paulster2 Its Holden Berlia 2007 model and i am in Australia

Comment: Since I don't know Holdens, I will let someone else answer. To that end, I would bet there is an access panel to the gas tank either under the back seat or in the trunk. You'd be looking for something with several (3 to 6) screws in it located in the floorpan sheet metal. Pull this panel, and underneath is the fuel pump access. Pull this access and the fuel pump is attached. Most of these will have re-usable rubber gaskets so have no fear. If you can do this, you can see what might be in the tank. Leave doors open when you do this so you don't get high on fumes. Replace as you took it apart.

Comment: FYI The Holden Berlina is basically a Chevy Lumina v6. According to Wikipedia at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your fuel filter is for. The worst thing that could happen when someone puts sand in your fuel tank is that you'll have to have the tank, pump and pipes cleaned and the filter replaced. If someone put water in the tank, you could simply fill up with fuel and drive around a bit. Water actually makes your car rev more smoothly at high RPM. Just get it out quickly (2 or 3 days) before corrosion starts.

Answer (score 1):

### Diesel

If someone put diesel into the tank of a gasoline/petrol engined car, you can expect an expensive repair may be necessary. However you would probably have noticed the damage.

[AA](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/fuels-and-environment/misfuelling.html) (not the one you might be thinking of)

### Sugar

Sugar does not dissolve in gasoline, so the main effect might be clogging of the fuel filters.

[Straight dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1587/does-putting-sugar-in-the-gas-tank-wreck-a-cars-engine)

### Sand

Ditto sand, this is heaver so is perhaps likely to mostly remain in the tank.